# A doubt regarding a property of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I just wanted to confirm that when we define a complex function $f (z) $, is it just a function in terms of $z $,  or also that in terms of $\overline  {z} $? This is because if the latter is true, then every function of the form $f (x, y) $ can be written in the form $g (z) $,  which I suppose will alter a lot of my complex analysis understanding.

Comment: Any complex number $w$ can be written (uniquely) as $w=\bar{z}$. Hence the complex conjugation is only another way to describe all complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You may use $2x=z+\bar z$ and $2iy=z-\bar z$ to rewrite $f(x,y)$ as $g(z,\bar z)$, but in general you cannot write it as $g(z)$. For example, consider $f(x,y)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

All the nice properties of complex functions (we should say analytical, holomorphic functions) don't hold if you have complex conjugation in the mix. So... if you want to do complex analysis, not every function $f(x,y)$ can be written with a complex argument without ruining math.

A very good example are polynomials. A complex polynomial of order $n$ has $n$ roots. A mixture of $z$ and $\overline{z}$ of order $n$ has who knows how many roots. Up to $2n$, I think, but I'm not sure. Also, there is no Taylor expansion for $f(z)=\overline{z}$ and so on. The function $f(z)=\overline{z}$ is not analytic, it does not follow the Cauchy equations and once you compose this function with an analytic function, you lose all the nice properties (and capability of doing anything useful with a function, such as derivatives, integrals, series expansion, application of other analytical functions...).

Comment: So you're saying $f (z)\neq f (z, \overline {z}) $?

Comment: Well, $f(z)$ is in principle a trivial function of $z$ and $\overline{z}$, but the other direction doesn't work: as soon as $\overline{z}$ appears in the function, the function can no longer be written as an analytical function of $z$.